# How to ask C# date of birth in a certain format with limitations?

Tags: c#, date

I'm very new to C# and I think I got something on my mind but can't quite figure it out.

So I got this school project that needs to ask the first name, last name and date of birth of the user but with certain limitations. I can figure the names out but the date problem persists.

The date of birth should be in `DD.MM.YYYY`. format and have certain limitations:

Date should be between `01-31`

Month between `01-12`

Year between `1900-2050`

I can get it to ask but it won't specify the format and I don't know what variable to use.

Comment: Please edit your question and share your code with us, and we would be happy to help.

Comment: I imagine you can just accept the input as a string and use `DateTime.TryParseExact()` to specify the format when converting that string to a `DateTime` value.  Note that the "limitations" you've defined do not accurately express a date value.  For example, "31.02.2018" is not a valid date.  Don't re-invent the wheel with dates, use the tools available to you.  In this case, parsing a `DateTime` from a `string`.

Comment: tried anything yet?

Comment: `I can get it to ask but it won't specify...` what is "it"`?  A Console program?  If not, try a DateTimePicker

Comment: Are you expecting many users coming from the future?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing and how you are doing it, if its a webform or similar you can use validators and regular expressions, or use a custom data validator.  That way it will be validated before the user submits it.

Answer (score 1):

To parse dates in custom format, [`DateTime.TryParse` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_TryParse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__) is best fit.

You just need to find culture, which uses your date format, for example `"fr-CH"`.

Then you use mentioned method to check if format of date was correct. It automatically checks if date is vaild, i.e. month is between 1 and 12, day of month is in correct range (1 through 28,29,30 or 31 depending on month and year).

You just need to additionally check the year.

Try this code (I used short-circuiting operator `&&`, so if parsing was successfull, then check the year):

```
DateTime dt;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-CH");
DateTimeStyles styles = DateTimeStyles.None;
if(DateTime.TryParse("28.01.2018", culture, styles, out dt)
  && dt.Year >= 1900 && dt.Year <= 2050) // here you check additionally if year is in correct range
    Console.WriteLine("Date successfully parsed!");
```

Comment: @Flydog57 Well, that was just example culture matching OP's date :)